# Donde y como se corrige el error en esta linea de SQL y Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
    PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE tb_producto SET cantidad='"+txtcantidad.getText()+"' WHERE nombre='"+txtbuscar.getText()+"'");
```

Donde esta el error y como se logra solucionar ayuda por favor!!

Answer (score 1):

El error es que estás usando mal el `PreparedStatement`, el cual es un elemento que existe para escribir código seguro contra la Inyección SQL.

Cuando se usan consultas preparadas (PreparedStatement), debes colocar marcadores de posición (`?`) y pasar los datos aparte, así evitas la Inyección.

Veamos:

```
/*Aquí escribes una consulta que será preparada (PreparedStatement)
 *No pones valores directos en ella, sino que usas ? para cada valor
 *Tampocos pones nada entre comillas simples ''*/
String strSQL="UPDATE tb_producto SET cantidad=? WHERE nombre=?";

/*Ahora preparas la consulta*/
PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement(strSQL);
/*Invocas los métodos adecuados para pasar valores según su tipo en la base de datos
 *Si la columna cantidad es numérica en la BD debes usar setInt
 *Quizá haga falta parsear a int el valor obtenido con txtcantidad.getText() en ese caso
 *Si es del tipo VARCHAR, CHAR, etc, debes usar setString
 *IMPORTANTE: Se setean tantos valores como signos de ? hay, en su orden, claro
 *Y se empieza desde 1...*/
pps.setInt(1, txtcantidad.getText());  //O bien: pps.setString(1, txtcantidad.getText());
pps.setString(2,txtbuscar.getText()); 

  /*Como info puedes obtener el número de registros actualizados*/
  int rowsUpdated = pps.executeUpdate(); 
  System.out.println("Filas actualizadas: " + rowsUpdated);
```

Recomiendo que leas el [tutorial de la documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) al respecto.

La Inyección SQL no es algo banal. Escribir código inseguro puede provocar que usuarios mal intencionados borren tus datos, tomen el control de tu BD y en algunos casos hasta de tu equipo.